# DataGrid that allows to interact with database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am looking for Datagrid that retrieves information from database along with below feature.

1. Should work with JSP
2. Provide Add, Edit and Remove options
3. Save to Database
4. Read from excel file.

Let me know if any one of you successfully implemented Datagrid with above features using any Ajax, Javascript based datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are loads out there. I'll start the ball rolling with DataTables - http://www.datatables.net

I've used this a lot and like it, there's have a paid option that handles CRUD - http://editor.datatables.net/ if you don't want to have to roll your own

It won't read directly from an Excel sheet though, you'll need to pass the data from it formatted correctly

Comment: DataTables is a paid one and I am looking for openSource that works with JSP.

Comment: Datatables is free, and opensource. Only the editor part is paid and you can roll your own editor fairly easily

Comment: It supports (PHP, C#, Perl, Ruby, AIR, Gears etc) and not JSP or JAVA. I am looking for one that works JSP and a DEMO code to integrate.

Comment: It supports anything, it's a front end grid. It just passes JSON back and forth.